# Android: how to add Layout into AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android-layout, android

I am trying to add a `LinearLayout` representing a little panel containing some elements to the main `AbsoluteLayout` of my `Activity`. 
I am using this code but the app crashes, this is the constructor of the panel class, that should add the view to the main layout. A similar code works to add runtime created buttons, but won't work for this.

```
public ButtonSetupPanel(String btnName, int keyCode, View v){
    AbsoluteLayout abs = (AbsoluteLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mainbg);
    LinearLayout panel = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSetupPanel);
    panel.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1023, 300));
    panel.setOnTouchListener(this);
    abs.addView(panel);
}
```

LogCat: (I am using StandOut library)

> 06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
>   com.vektor.amapper.windows.MainWindow@413e44b0 with Intent { act=SHOW
>   cmp=com.vektor.amapper/.windows.MainWindow (has extras) }:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 06-12 22:43:22.268:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2507)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-12 22:43:22.268:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-12 22:43:22.268:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-12 22:43:22.268:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8146): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   com.vektor.amapper.windows.ui.ButtonSetupPanel.(ButtonSetupPanel.java:18)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   com.vektor.amapper.windows.MainWindow.createAndAttachView(MainWindow.java:86)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   wei.mark.standout.ui.Window.(Window.java:150) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   wei.mark.standout.StandOutWindow.show(StandOutWindow.java:1079) 06-12
>   22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):     at
>   wei.mark.standout.StandOutWindow.onStartCommand(StandOutWindow.java:382)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   com.vektor.amapper.windows.MainWindow.onStartCommand(MainWindow.java:150)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>   06-12 22:43:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(8146):   ... 10 more

**Update:** I found out that the problem is that since this `LinearLayout` is in another XML file i need to inflate the other layout file and show the defined view (the LinearLayout). How to proceed?

**Update2:** I used this code to get the Needed View

```
public ButtonSetupPanel(String btnName, int keyCode, View v){
    AbsoluteLayout abs = (AbsoluteLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mainbg);
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.btnsetup , null);
    LinearLayout panel = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSetupPanel);
    view.removeView(panel);
    panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    panel.setX(512f);
    panel.setY(300f);
    panel.setOnTouchListener(this);
    abs.addView(panel);
}
```

Comment: AbsoluteLayout was deprecated in API level 3

Comment: I added the LogCat. Can it be the fact that the panel is defined inside another xml file (not the same as my main layout) to cause the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated since API level 3 ?
Try to use RelativeLayout.

You can recreate absolute positioning by adding your child views to a RelativeLayout and set the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to have only default values except width, height, marginTop and marginLeft. The top and left margin will be similar to top and left in AbsoluteLayout. Also, negative margins are supported.

Source:
[Alternative to AbsoluteLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753287/2281717)

Comment: I am afraid that despite the Layout I am using there is some error in my code.

Comment: my advise to you - use RelativeLayout - it can make the same things as Absolute and even better.
ButtonSetupPanel.java:18 - what code in 18 line?

Comment: the setLayoutParams line. I'm afraid that the error is that the panel view is in a different xml file and this causes nullpointerexception