# Long Press Android to Java

Tags: java, android, awtrobot, motionevent, long-press

I'm trying to program a **Mouse via Wifi TCP**. `Client is on Android and Server on Java.` I'm trying to detect a **LongPress on Android** and send this information to Java.

**Android:**
I need to implement `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` but I don´t know what to do after this code.

**Java:**
How the class `Robot` receive those parameters who `MotionEvent` sends, and how implement the `LongPress` on both client and server.

Comment: You need to learn a lot more about android/java/etc before you continue. Your questions are very basic and show that you should complete a full tutorial on both subjects before continuing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : How to implement longpress manually in touch event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047531/android-how-to-implement-longpress-manually-in-touch-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a button.setonlongclicklistener? Check out this example: http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-long-press-event-handle-example.html

Comment: Thank you, that helped me to implement the Longclicklistener :).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(motionEvent.isActionDown())
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
          onLongPressListener.fire();
     }
  }, 500);
```

You can send as messages delayeds and clear the messages with an ID.