# Android WHILE longpress event

Tags: java, android, long-press

How do I perform something while the something is long pressed and something when it is released?
I am using Gesture Detector to handle events

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android/11679788#11679788

Answer (score 0):

The longpress is a specific action. For your purposes I think you will have to look at `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`

[ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) is when a press has started.

[ACTION_UP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) is when it is released.

Comment: So how do I customize this onTouch for a LongPress?

Comment: put the "something1" you want to execute in ACTION_DOWN, put the other "something2" you want to execute in ACTION_UP. When user presses down, "something1" will fire. When they let go, "something2" will fire. Is this not what you want? If not please describe when you want things to happen.

Comment: In this case, 'something1' will fire immediately when the user touches the screen, I want it to  fire up when he has long pressed the screen and keep going on till he releases the screen. As he releases, 'something2' should immediately fire.

Comment: I'd find out how long a long-press is (`ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()` will tell you), on first ACTION_DOWN set up a handler/timer to fire "something1" after that period of time (cancel it if you get ACTION_UP before then, this indicates the user has not pressed as long as a long-press). First time you get ACTION_UP after that time, fire "something2". This will do what you describe above.