# How to implement LONG click (or touch) on LiveWallpaper

Tags: android

I am building a LiveWallpaper.

I detect touch events to perform certain actions.

```
   @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("home")) {
                if (firstdoor.contains(x, y))
                    {goToShoppin();return;}
   ...OTHER STUFF
```

Now the point is that the surface seems to be quite sensitive and when the user touches the Wallpaper happens that I perform more than one of the desired actions.

Therefore I was thinking about implementing a "LongTouch".

Please any suggestion on how could I do it?

Comment: you can go with timer.

Comment: Use GestureDetector. You should see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7921439/2652124

Comment: u can use setOnLongClickListener() method

Comment: `implements` your current Activity with `onLongClickListener` then override the method `void onLongClick() { }` and handle what ever you want

Comment: I think this link will surely help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html