# Long press in GestureDetector also fires on tap

Tags: android, gesture

I tried implementing code from this question: [Detecting a long press with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android), but it always detects a long press, if even I just tap it. My code is as follows (I extended `ImageView`, because more code is in it, not relevant for this question):

```
public class EbsImageView extends ImageView  {
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
        }
    public boolean onSingleTapUP(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Press detected");

            // don't consume, we want the long press to fire if it was a 
            // long press
        return false;
        }
    });

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: return false from onTouchEvent()

Comment: @Eu.Dr. makes no difference, I also tried the code from here: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html but the same problem.

Comment: where is Your @Override annotation at onLongPress and onSingleTapUp? It´s just a copy/paste fail?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs they are not there, but even if I put them there, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think You should return true from onSingleTapUp

Comment: @Opiatefuchs onSingleTapUp isn't even fired at all. From the example from the Android docs, only `onDown`, `onShowPress` and `onLongPress` are fired. Always, whatever gesture I make. I am now working on a solution that uses the `View`'s `onLongClickListener`.

Comment: ok, have You tried to use OnGestureListener instead of SimpleOnGestureListener? Like described in the API for SimpleOnGestureListener: "does nothing and return false for all applicable methods. "

Comment: onSingleTapUp can't be fired as you don't override it. Instead you add a method onSingleTapUP. Note the last letter (P) should be lowercase while yours is uppercase, which does matter in JAVA. That's why @Opiatefuchs asked you about the Override annotation. If you add it, the compiler should warn you that you're actually not overriding.

Answer (score 29):

You need to override `onDown` and make it `return true`. The following code worked for me:

```
class SimpleGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
      // triggers first for both single tap and long press
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
      // triggers after onDown only for single tap
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
      // triggers after onDown only for long press
      super.onLongPress(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still triggers for me anyway

Answer (score 5):

Solution [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25487744/3736955) works (returning `true` in `onDown()`). I have also made it work by setting `clickable` and `focusable` property of View to `true` before setting `GestureDetector`.

```
val gestureDetectorCompat = GestureDetectorCompat(context, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            // log "Single Tap Confirm"
            return true
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            // log "Long Press"
        }
    })
image_stateful.isClickable = true
image_stateful.isFocusable = true
image_stateful.setOnTouchListener { _, event -> gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event) }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in my comment, you should distinguish between `onSingleTapUp()` and `onSingleTapUP()`. Using the Override annotation is a good practice.

I'm a bit confused because the title of your question seems to indicate that a long press also fires the on tap event, while the text of your question says it the other way around. That is that a tap fires a long press event. If the later is the case, try returning true from your `onSingleTapUp()`. This works for me using the `SimpleGestureListener`:

```
class SimpleGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

  @Override
  public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
     //...
    return super.onDown(event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
    //...
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    //...
    super.onLongPress(event);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.