# OnLongClickListener not getting triggerred on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am going mad and yet not understanding what mistake am I making, Please help.

I have a `ViewPager` in my layout xml, I have a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for this pager. Basically am loading different fragments on this `ViewPager`.

But the number of fragments will be decided by users certain action and to start off with `ViewPager` will not load any fragments, I mean `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` count will be 0.

Now I want user to long hold `ViewPager` to trigger some action. But when I add `OnLongClickListener` to viewpager `onLongClick` method never triggers :(

Here is my code,

```
pageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.d("sandeep","YES");
            return false;
      }
});
```

What is the mistake here?? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: return true  insted of false

Comment: @ak sacha: Control never reaches here :( no point in returning true or false here

Comment: ok, so then you can set the LongClickListener on the layout that you're inflating.

Comment: @ak sacha: I really appreciate your effort you are putting in to help me :) but a small problem here, Issue is the layout contains just a PageViewer, So ViewPagerCovering whole view of my layout all touches are being inercepted by ViewPager there is no way my layout gets any touch :( I hope I made my point clear :) If you din get please lemme know I'll try explain better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On viewPager you can set OnTouchListener to get the gestureDetector working for longpress detection.
But I would suggest you use this on the fragment parent layout that is being loaded into the viewpager.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

    // Called when the activity is first created. 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
        // application context and an implementation of
        // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,new Gesture());

        yourViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                 return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

  class Gesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
       public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {
       }

       public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev) {
         //your long press code here
       }

       public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
       float distanceY) {
       } 

       public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
       float velocityY) {
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` doesn't work with the `ViewPager` itself because it's capturing touch events to be able to scroll between pages.

You should set an onTouchListener, capture the `ACTION_UP` motion event. And don't forget to remove the listener when the pager has items.

Comment: I realized that OnTouchListener gets triggered properly on ViewPager but requirement is I want user to hold on to ViewPager for sometime to trigger some actions (like on holding for 2 seconds show some menu) How can I achieve it with OnTouchListener ?? Anyway up voting your answer good observation :)

Comment: This is not a very good solution, but this might work. Take a button having width and height = `fill_parent` and then make the button background transparent. Put the `onLongClickListener` with that button.

Comment: Check this answer, I think is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android/11679788#11679788

@ReazMurshed answer is also another good option.

Comment: @Reaz Murshed,emanzanomarcos : hehehehehe :) I just did the same trick with a view rather than the button :) true that it works but somehow am not feeling that its correct :( emanzanomarcos : ok lemme check your link