# how to ignore long press in the whole App's area?

Tags: android, multi-touch

I made an App for my children.

The problem is that he hold the tablet with the thumbs slightly inside the view margins.

By doing so, he can't click on view's buttons while one hand is holding the device.

There is a way to ignore all the long presses on the entire App?

My aim is to let him to click on the view's button while holding the device with thumbs inside the view margins.

I already searched with Google but without lucky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate . Check this out :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android

Or checkout below tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html

Comment: Unfortunately the touch event is related to a a view, you should override the onTouchEvent on each "root container" of your UI

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi It isn't a problem, I'll create a class that handle that feature. Did you know how can achieve that function per activity?