# is it possible to detect long press on an app icon in Android?

Tags: android, long-press

I am trying to make a code to detect a long press on my app icon. When my app icon is long pressed to open the menu(app info, uninstall, and other shortcuts), another screen should be put up so that the user can't get access the options. I just need to know how to detect long press on my app icon.

Have read [Detecting a long press with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android), but there is no answer related on how to detect the same on my android app icon?

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is for questions/problems related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Please let us know if you found an answer, I'm looking for the same thing!

Comment: It looks like the "Detoxify" app is able to do this so there is definitely a way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make shortcuts for launcher icon.

Look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

Comment: I've looked into this, and made some test shortcuts. Is there any way to be notified when these shortcuts are displayed? i.e. when the launcher icon is long-pressed?