# Is it possible to suppress the "Long Hold" (aka "long press") pop-up dialog on Android browsers via CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, css, long-press

I'm having a heckuva time trying to find a way to use ***javascript*** or ***css*** (not Java) to prevent Android devices from showing the pop up dialog when long-pressing on an html element like an image or anchor in a web page.

I'm trying to make a carousel and if I hold the left or right arrow down on my carousel, a window pops up asking me to open in a new tab, save the image, etc.  I can do this easily enough on iOS/Safari with a css rule.

[image: Screen shot of the dialog I'm trying to suppress]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

how are you setting your setOnLongClickListener and onTouch?

make sure it's similar to this

```
setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

      activity.openContextMenu(view);  

     return true;  // avoid extra click events

    }

});

setOnTouch(new View.OnTouchListener(){

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){

    switch(e.getAction & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

      // do drag/gesture processing. 

    }

// you MUST return false for ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, for long click to work
// you can return true for ACTION_MOVEs that you consume. 
// DOWN/UP are needed by the long click timer.
// if you want, you can consume the UP if you have made a drag - so that after 
// a long drag, no long-click is generated.

    return false;

  }

});

setLongClickable(true);
```

code curtosy of Sanjay Manohar
[Detect touch press vs long press vs movement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement)