# Pass click event through the view android

Tags: android, click

I have frame layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widgetView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widgetOverlayFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false" >
</LinearLayout>
```

First layout contains widget layout, and second one is transparent and receives onLongClick for dragging method.That works, the problem is when i want to interact with widget, to click something, click event is taken by overlayFrame. How can i pass click event trough overlayFrame to widgetView?

EDIT:

Now I'm trying to attach GestureLister to overlayFrame LinearLayout, to somehow see difference between MotionEvent that represent single click and long click. The problem that I'm facing is that OnLongPress in gesture listener is always called whatever I do, single click or long click.

Is there an explanation for this behavior? Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using GestureListener you can override the onTouchListener in this way.

This will call longPress when the timer runs out and if an up comes in between it will cancel the LongPress

```
   CountDownTimer c;
    long time=5000;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                c= new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                  time=millisUntilFinished;
                           }

                          public void onFinish() {
                                 Log.i("","LONG PRESS");
                           }}.start();

            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (time>0) {
                    Log.i("example","short click");
                    c.cancel();
                }
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, that works for detection perfectly...how do I now pass click to layer beneath?

Answer (score 6):

In my case I added flag to layoutParams of my view, which should have passed a touch event under:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
```

This way view will ignore all touches (like view with visibility GONE)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the overlay's attribute `android:focusable="false"` or `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` would be enough.

You could also make your own overlay widget and override its `onInterceptTouchEvent` method to return false always.

```
public class NotTouchableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    // Override constructors
    // ...

   @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to override onTouch instead of onInterceptTouchEvent.

Comment: hehe, I've did that, but now onLongClick on overlayLayout isn't called. And i can't drag items.

Comment: How can i make difference in onTouch between click and long click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement

Comment: I can't get this work. Can you be more specific. There isn't accepted answer either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a `GestureListener` on the top layout, you should create your own class that extends `LinearLayout` and to override it's `onTouchEvent` method.
There you can implement the logic of long click \ short click etc.

The click events will first be sent to the widget layout, and only if it doesn't handle them (hence it's `onTouchEvent` returns `false`), you will get them on the top layout.

**edit:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widgetView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:gravity="center" >
</LinearLayout>

<com.example.touchtesting.MyLinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widgetOverlayFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false" >
</com.example.touchtesting.MyLinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

change the `com.example.touchtesting` to the name of your package.
and this is the class:

```
        public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

        public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        private long startClick = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            switch (ev.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startClick = ev.getEventTime();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (ev.getEventTime() - startClick < 500) {
                        Log.i("example","short click");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.i("example","long click");
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: i will try that now ;) tnx...it makes sence...hope this works...i've lost a days with this.

Comment: The widget layer doesn't get short click...:/ Detection works fine, and I return false on short click, but widget stays still and doesn't react on that action.

Comment: One more thing...I need to detect Long click on Action Down...I'm working on custom launcher...you know how widgets are moving around the screen? OnLong click starts drag...

Comment: i've did that...if i didn't my app will crash...it's running...but widget doesn't intercept click event...

Answer (score 0):

To get the long clicks to pass through the widgetView `LinearLayout` add `android:longClickable="true"`. (For ordinary clicks add `android:clickable="true"`)

So widgetView becomes:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widgetView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:longClickable="true">
</LinearLayout>
```