# Pass touches to the view under

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, android-activity, touch-event

In my app I have a fragment on top of the activity. The fragment is filling the whole screen. Part of the fragment is a transparent View and you can see the views under (that belong to the activity). Is there a way to transfer the touch events to the views that are under the transparent View of the fragment?
Thanks!

Comment: this should be standard behaviour I think as long as the transparent view (or it's parents) has no onclicklistener

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your overriden `onTouchEvent` method inside the fragment return `false`, it passes the touch event to the lower layer views.

Answer (score 39):

simplest way :

form here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34436589/3818437

Declare your fragment not clickable/focusable by using

```
android:clickable="false"

android:focusable="false"
```

or

```
v.setClickable(false)

v.setFocusable(false)
```

The click events should be dispatched to the fragment's parent now.

> **Note:** To achieve this, you have to add a click to its direct parent. or set android:clickable="false" and
> android:focusable="false" to its direct parent to pass listener to
> further parent.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: this doesnt work for layouts overlapping inside frame

Answer (score 3):

You can use special flag in layoutParams.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955777/2885859)

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
```

Comment: and in xml file?