# Android : Focus on a view much like selecting a layer in photoshop

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout, viewgroup

Say I have the following layout :

```
<FrameLayout>
    <Button>
    <ImageView
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:width="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

`ImageView` spans the whole screen and covers the button below it, but I would still like to be able to click the button. Is this possible? What I want is to change focus to a certain view, ignoring the view hierarchy. In this case I would like to be able to push the button, ignoring the Imageview above it. Is this possible? Something like `ImageView.setClickable(false)` or layering in Photoshop.

Comment: Why not attaching a click listener directly on the  `ImageView`? Your view hierarchy will be simpler.

Comment: May be you should have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283444/android-image-button it can solve your problem by integrating the image directly to the button itself.

Comment: Those aren't what i'm trying to achieve. There's a lot of workaround for this but what i'm trying to achieve is to be able to access a view below a view, ignoring the view above it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why the button can't be on top of the ImageView?
If the reason is that the button should not be visible, you could set its background to @android:color/transparent.

Alternatively, have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676712/pass-touches-to-the-view-under)?