# Make transparent part of the view pass over touches and keep touches on a visible part

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-viewholder

There is views container (blue) which is set for the almost full width of the screen. Sometimes views which are displayed inside this container require not to have the full width of the container - thus we show only visible part (green) and other part of the view is transparent(area inside container except visible view). At the same time other views (purple) can be placed behind the transparent part of the views container.

The question is - how to make such views clickable through the transparent part of container? At the time visible view (green) should proceed touches with its own manner.

View declaration is done with help of XML not compose.

**Upd1**: by design visible view (green) should be always on top. Thus purple view is always behind visible view (green) and container

**Upd2**: in theory its possible to assign correct width to visible view and container, thus X button of the purple view wont be overlapped by transparent part of the container and clickable, but it would be hard to achieve in existing codebase because many views and their sizes should be rewritten

**Upd3**: purple view is showed by third party app (not by us)

**Upd4**: the green view is swipable - left&right, so that's why the container is needed

[image]

Comment: So your container is above the purple view, but also has to behave like behind? Can you give a better example about how this works? What is container _containing_, is the VisibleView(green) clickable? but only the part that is not above the purple view? can you only close purple view by the "X" or tapping anywhere else? let us know a bit in more detail how you'd want this to work, I think you may be complicating your existence by using "an inadequate" hierarchy for your use-case.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini >So your container is above the purple view, but also has to behave like behind? yes. >What is container containing, is the VisibleView(green) clickable?  - yes, only visible part (green color) >can you only close purple view by the "X" or tapping anywhere else? - only by tapping X.

Comment: Since changing the views/layout seems to be out of the scope of what you have, perhaps you may need to rely on an onTouchEvent that can determine where the touch is in relation to the whole screen, and manually check whose view to dispatch the action. Alternatively, maybe creating a "fake" view on top of some parts that can dispatch the touch to the views below, I mean it's all a bit hacky because it doesn't feel like a "normal" android layout hierarchy. You're _breaking_ the View.java behavior by attempting to define a custom click rectangle, perhaps a custom view (green) could help.

Comment: So you have control over the container and greenview, *but not the purple view*, right?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini right. I also add some updates in the description.

Answer (score 0):

To Recap:

- You have a transparent "full-width" container, that inside contains GreenViews.
- Behind this container, you have 3rd-party PurpleViews (with a X close button).
- You want to ensure that the purple views can be closed, so as long as they are (or should) be visible given the existing transparency.
- You also want to make sure that if a user taps your Green Views, that those views receive the events, as they are clickable.

I don't see a "drag-and-drop" solution out of this, considering you have several restrictions in what you can change and not.

One option I can think of, is to add a view *inside* your container, to intercept the tap and deliver it to the purple view.

```
                  _____________
[ container  [green][fake view]]
                 |             |
                 |   purple    |
                 |_____________|
```

So now your "fake" view could simulate and pass the touch to the Purple view.

Another option would be to set a touch interceptor on your container (or above) and decide based on the X/Y of the touch, to which view the event should be dispatched (this may be more work, but again, we don't have your project in front of us, so only you can tell that).

A *discarded* idea was to restrict the width of the green view, but that was not possible because it would be too much work according to you.

UPDATE Based on Update4: if the green view is swipeable, if you elect to use a fake view, you may need to "resize" it, as you swipe left/right to enlarge/shrink its area.
Good luck ;)

Answer (score -1):

As long as I know, you cannot change whether certain part of the view is clickable and certain is not. Its either full view clickable or not.

In your case, since the container is taking full width it'll be either entirely clickable or not.

Solution to your problem would be:

A: Don't render full width and make the left out part transparent. Since there's no use of the transparent part, just render till the part which is visible(green). This way the purple view will be visible.

B: If you somehow know that your visible view(green) is taking full width, then place a cross icon above the green view, let purple view behind. and set a click listener on the cross icon.

As a reference, take a look at this answer: [Pass touches to the view under](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676712/pass-touches-to-the-view-under)

Comment: thanks for your comment:) Sorry I didnt mentioned in the description that by design there is no way to place purple view above green one. Approach A is only one solution what we have one but it requires to rewrite/recheck many views and their size dependencies, I will add this info to the description.