# How to create multiple activities touch overlay app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout, touch

Im creating overlay app that shows over some games, i want to be able to use joystick in game / scroll webpage and click my overlay buttons that are at the screen bottom. How can i achieve this?

Something like keyboard can do, you can push/hold keyboard keys, and scroll apps at the same time

Already tried WindowManager with diffrent flags, but its not working - I should be able to click my button that LOG something for example, while scrolling web page at the same time, without touch interrupting

Im granting    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>` to my app, and im using this to display my overlay `
private fun startOverlayService() {
mOverlayView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null)

```
    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
        },
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START

    mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    mWindowManager?.addView(mOverlayView, params)`
```

Comment: Are you trying to draw on top of other apps?  There's a special permission you need for that, which needs to be both requested in the manifest and granted by the user manually.  If you're using that and still having issues, we need to see how you're trying to do it

Comment: Some of the answers here may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676712/pass-touches-to-the-view-under

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH was the answer!

```
   val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )
```