# Android Distinguishing Between Click and Drag dispatchTouchEvent

Tags: android

I am currently using [dispatchTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) to grab touch events, is there an easy way to distinguish between a click and a "drag" stylt gesture?

Answer (score 1):

`DispatchTouchEvent` is called with a `MotionEvent` parameter. Method `getAction` within `MotionEvent` can return

- **ACTION_DOWN**
- **ACTION_MOVE**
- **ACTION_UP**
- **ACTION_CANCEL**

Then set on **ACTION_DOWN** flag isClick.  If there is **ACTION_MOVE** clear isClick flag.

```
switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        isClick = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (isClick) {
            //TODO Click action
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        isClick = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Seems like no matter how brief I tap, the action move event always get's fired.

Comment: Check my other answer which introduces a movement threshold before setting isClick to false: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485989/1373248

Comment: I implemented a similar solution yesterday.  You might want to update this answer.

Comment: This will not reliably work because small twitches in the finger will trigger `ACTION_MOVE` thus nullifying your click action.

Comment: @user2968401: True!  You cam implement move threshold : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement/16485989#16485989

Answer (score 0):

set up a threshold limit.When you move the pointer within a small range make it recognized as a click or else a movement