# How to dynamically add Imageview on Layout using onDraw method in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place a pin image over a Layout.The layout have a Map Image(Not Google map).I want to fit the pins dynamically when I long click the map Image.Please send a sample how to draw this method ...

Comment: Is the image scroll- or zoomable in any way?

Comment: SO isn't a site to request code, first you have to try to do something and then post your results. I would tell you to use the `setOnTouchListener` on that Map Image, and detect the touch time with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485989/1403997). Then you can either add the view to a layout above the Map Image, or override your Map Image `onDraw` to draw the pin. I'll give you the full answer if you at least try this.