# How to detect click and longClick on canvas

Tags: android, onclick, android-canvas, onlongclicklistener

Hi i'm working on a Battleships game in Android and currently i'm trying to implement the ship positioning activity.

I have a custum view with onDraw representing the board on which you position the ships.

I want to be able to rotate ships by singletapping them and drag a ship by longclicking it. The thing is i can't just use onClick and onLongClick because i need to know where was the click on the canvas. I tried using onTouch but that didn't work. I also tried using GestureDetector but it just meseed up everything.

Do you have any suggestions on how to approach this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to know where was the click on the canvas

You have a custom view, hence you can easily use `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`. Just override the `onTouchEvent()` of your CustomView and use the `onLongPress` of the `GestureDetector`. I would suggest you to handle this within the CustomView itself, rather than do it in `Activity` or `Fragment`. This would keep things modularized.

You can follow the code below to get this done:

**CustomView.java**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

        private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;
        private LongPressGestureListener longPressGestureListener;

        CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            longPressGestureListener= new LongPressGestureListener(this);
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, longPressGestureListener);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            // Handle any other event here, if not long press.
            return true;
        }
}
```

**LongPressGestureListener.java**

```
public class LongPressGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onLongPress(e);
            // e will give you the location and everything else you want
            // This is where you will be doing whatever you want to.
            int eIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(e);
            float eX = MotionEventCompat.getX(e, eIndex);
            float eY = MotionEventCompat.getY(e, eIndex);
            Log.d("X:Y = " + eX + " : " + eY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `View.OnTouchListener`.

1. Set the touch listener to your canvas with `view.setOnTouchListener(listener)`.
2. Implement your touch listener. You will need to implement the `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method. In this method, you will have access to the touch event, and you will be able to decide, if it is a simple click, a long press, etc, and do the appropriate action.

You can read more about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485989/4170584) on SO.