# How to make onLongClick work on a EditText that's disabled?

Tags: android

I have `EditText` which I want to disable and enable `onLongClick`, but I'm unable to long click on them after they are disabled. What do do?

This was the code I wrote for the purpose:

```
for (int j = 0; j < noOfDigits; j++) {
        final int k = j;

        etReference[j].setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if(etReference[k].isEnabled()) {
                    etReference[k].setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(!etReference[k].isEnabled()){
                    etReference[k].setEnabled(true);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabled components means that it shouldn't fire interect events.

If you are really wanting to do that, you should setOnTouchEvent and parse a LongClick by yourself (DOWN + NOT MOVE + 500ms).

Comment: No, too complex, you should learn how to parse events based on its type. All I can say is that you should fire a postDelayed to a Handler on DOWN and cancel it if a move occurs, but be aware, move events are common than your think, so you should have some if based on the distance moved, something about 16dp works fine.

Comment: Check the answer theres a implementation of this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement